# Is this unit properly supported?

Tags: plywood, screws

I am designing a unit constructed entirely of wood. The small (innermost) cylinders are 16" and the big (outermost) ones are 32". The platforms are 3/4" BC plywood.

[image: Front]

My concern is the height of the cylinders may allow the unit to tilt based on where placed relative to the platform, given some distribution of weight.

[image: Bottom]

If you look at underside of left, topmost platform, there are three cylinders. The two on left are big and the one on right is small.

I divided platform into four segments to demonstrate relationship with placement of cylinders (the platform in real life is just one piece). Each segment is 8" x 1' and each cylinder is perfectly centered to one of three. The bounding box of the platform is 2'x 2'.

This placement extends to rest of unit as I try showing below.

[image: Front and bottom]

I am using ~2" screws to fasten cylinders to plywood, but my test doesn't seem secure. The plywood itself is quite heavy, but I expect animals to be running on it too so the moderate weight load is an additional concern.

Would screw length/thickness/type determine if the unit can be supported this way? Or should cylinders be placed at each corner instead? I didn't purposely because I like this aesthetic better.

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  This question needs some additional information to be answered well.    What are the dimensions of the assembly including diameter of the posts, sizes of the platforms (a plan would be helpful), and what the platforms are used for (loads anticipated).  Will this be used for people traffic?

Comment: Triangles, never forget triangles...

Comment: Personally this doesn't strike too many alarm bells with me given how numerous parts connect with other parts not only in one spot (which you see in many cat towers for example). But you say animals without specifying type or weight, or how fast they might be expected to be moving; these are important details to properly guesstimate whether this is viable — for cats I'd say OK, for dogs maybe not so much. What wood the cylinders are made from is also definitely a factor so be sure to add that detail to the Q when you edit.

Comment: *"Would screw length/thickness/type determine if the unit can be supported this way?"* Yes, very much so in all three cases. There are previous Answers here that will give you information on all three factors so it would be worthwhile to search for them. Click on the screws tag as an easy starting point, then maybe search 'manually' in case some previous relevant Questions weren't tagged.